# automated file upload selenium ide 2.8 on mac

Tags: javascript, file-upload, automation, selenium-ide, firefox-os

I am experiencing a problem executing automated uploading of a file onto a website.

I'm using selenium IDE version 2.8 via firefox 31 on a Mac to test the process of the web system through a browser in my work.
At one point of the process it requires me to upload an excel file.

I have searched many forums and blogs for solution specifically to work on MacOS X with Firefox with Selenium IDE but none helped.

In my script, I have:

`command : click`

`Target : name=...`

`value :`

this line will click on the button which have a text word 'select file'
and the 'File Upload' dialog window will pop out for me to select the file i want to download

command : Type
Target : driver.FindElement(By.Id("File Upload"))
Value : /Users/...../excel.xlsx

this line supposed to find the element by id path in 'file upload' and select the path of the file which is stated by me in the value column.

problem occured:
[error] Element driver.FindElement(By.Id("File Upload")) not found

As far as I understand, im not sure if it is correct but from what i read and understand, somewhat works for others but wont work for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For this part:

command : Type Target : driver.FindElement(By.Id("File Upload")) Value : /Users/...../excel.xlsx

Can you change the target to id=File Upload ?

Comment: that was one of the first thing i tried at the start, but because of the upload file button the script execute the clicking on the browser will open a mac window dialog for me to choose the file. Generally i keep getting error of Element not found, Be it id=File Upload or driver.FindElement(By.Id("File Upload"))

Comment: Thats quite strange, thats how I've actioned a file upload in one of my automated tests. Perhaps our elements work differently?
type | id=file-input | /Users/Dan/Downloads/NewPOFile.csv

Answer (score 0):

the popup you are talking about is a OS popup you can't simply use it with selenium 
send the key to the tag with xpath something like " **//input[@type='file']** "
and then submit the form

Comment: does the version of the selenium ide and the browser type (chrome, FF) affects the type of element to specify in the command column?

Comment: the xpath is same for all IDE and browser just be exact with the path
to test try it manually that is you click the input tag is prompt to select a file and when you select a file it automaticlly uploads it for you if it need to press some sort of submit button then you need to deal with that too   :) happy learning

Comment: thanks a lot. I just got informed, actually the website i'm working on has some bugs on the interface so it doesnt show the path of the file but anyways " //input[@type='file'] " is working for me now.